# Width of layout in oncreate function is 0

Tags: android, width, oncreate

Width of layout in oncreate function, I need this size but your valor is 0. Here some of my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    LinearLayout layout_principal=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pru);

    int mywidth=layout_principal.getWidth();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams txt_sep_principal_Params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            mywidth/2);
         TextView txt_sep_principal=new TextView(this);
         txt_sep_principal.setLayoutParams(txt_sep_principal_Params);
         txt_sep_principal.setText("text of my code");
         TextView txt_sep_principal2=new TextView(this);
         txt_sep_principal2.setLayoutParams(txt_sep_principal_Params);
         txt_sep_principal2.setText("Text of my code");
    layout_principal.addView(txt_sep_principal);
    layout_principal.addView(txt_sep_principal2);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line

```
 LinearLayout layout_principal=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pru);
```

Try add these lines of code.

```
layout_principal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout_principal.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `layout` may not have been completely finished drawing. Try posting a `runnable` on it. Something like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    LinearLayout layout_principal=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pru);
    layout_principal.post(new Runnable()
    {       
      public void run()
      {
       int mywidth=layout_principal.getWidth();
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams txt_sep_principal_Params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
       mywidth/2);
       TextView txt_sep_principal=new TextView(this);
       ...
    }
 });
```

**Edit**

```
public class YourActivty extends Activity
{
     // These are declarations
     TextView tv;
     Button btn;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // these are initializations
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someId);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someOtherId);
```

See the comments in my code. **Declaring** them this way makes them available to the *whole* `Activity`. You can't initialize them before calling `setContentView()` and certainly not outside of a method. Obviously, you need to replace the sample `View`s I have used with your own.

Comment: Write the full header of the function Please

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: i think anonymous declaration confuse him

Comment: this line "layout_principal.post(new Runnable()",this is complete?

Comment: If you include the lines below it

Comment: @mhplur [See this section of the Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: thanks but not work. I have to declare layout_principal as final, and shows me error when creating Textview

Comment: I knew I should have mentioned that. Declare them as memeber variables (before `onCreate()` and outside of any method). Then initialize them where you need

Comment: LinearLayout layout_principal=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pru);
 TextView txt_sep_principal=new TextView(this);
 TextView txt_sep_principal2=new TextView(this); I put this before OnCreate method, and the rest within the function run () but it stops the application.

Comment: fails, the application stops.

Comment: Ok, I can't help without knowing more. How have you put the code, what exception are you getting and where, ...?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION:Main java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Yes, that is not helpful. Something is `null` is all that tells me. You will need to edit your post and add the full logcat as well as add the new code

Answer (score 0):

It's too early to get the size of layout in oncreate method

try this code :

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
 //Here you can get the size!
   Toast.makeText(this,""+ Layout.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Look full code here :

```
LinearLayout layout_principal;
    int mywidth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        layout_principal =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pru);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams txt_sep_principal_Params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                mywidth/2);
             TextView txt_sep_principal=new TextView(this);
             txt_sep_principal.setLayoutParams(txt_sep_principal_Params);
             txt_sep_principal.setText("text of my code");
             TextView txt_sep_principal2=new TextView(this);
             txt_sep_principal2.setLayoutParams(txt_sep_principal_Params);
             txt_sep_principal2.setText("Text of my code");
        layout_principal.addView(txt_sep_principal);
        layout_principal.addView(txt_sep_principal2);
        }


     @Override
     public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
      //Here you can get the size!
       mywidth=layout_principal.getWidth();
      }
```

Comment: its override method put it your class  as any method may be after onCreate method

Comment: where I put "layout_principal LinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.pru)"? not recognizing me in onWindowFocusChanged()

Comment: you will put it as field in code , take look on edit answer also

Comment: Sorry, the application runs, but the width does not recognize me, I get 0.